# Como contar palavras repetidas em uma string e achar sua posição?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Imagine o Alfabeto, nesse alfabeto tem palavras de A-Z, mas de repente surge várias letras A, como:

**A**-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-**A**-J-K-L-**A**-M-**A**-N-O-P-Q-**A**

A variável `nomes` abaixo, é esse alfabeto. A variável `procurar` só vai servir para mim escolher qual palavra *repetida* eu quero ver na variável `nomes`.

Neste modelo:

```
string procurar = "cachorro";
string nomes = "vaca cachorro vaca cachorro gato cavalo";
int index = ??
int total = ??
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Mas contar todas as palavras repetidas ou apenas a palavra que está na variável `procurar` ?

Comment: contar as palavras que está na variável `nomes`. A variável `procurar` serve para eu procurar o nome repetido na variável `nomes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vê se te ajuda:

```
string procurar = "cachorro";
string nomes = "vaca cachorro vaca cachorro gato cavalo";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(nomes, procurar);
foreach (Match item in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", procurar, item.Index));
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("achado {0} nomes ", matches.Count));
```

Funcionando no https://dotnetfiddle.net/dqjc8B